# Better options for action buttons in 'Cancel' Pop up

Tags: usability, website-design, interaction-design, user-behavior, buttons

My users have options to 'Cancel Order' that they have placed. When user clicks on 'Cancel Order', a confirmation pop up appears asking the user if he/she really wants to 'Cancel the Order' or 'Not Cancel it'. I have designed a pop up with button labels 'Yes Cancel' and 'Discard' but I feel Cancel and Discard both looks like similar options and might confuse the user.

[image]

What are other better alternatives to these button labels?

Comment: Typically I would put the positive on the left and the negative on the right. It looks like the objective of your process is to cancel the order, so the positive here would be to cancel. The negative I would reword to 'No - retain the order' or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Cancelling order at this point is not something which would be suitable for the business and it will also remove the order from user's cart. Hence it can be termed as a negative action which needs to have that negative warmth to it.

Coming over to the discard button, I think you should replace it with a more contextual text such as "No, don't cancel" with a positive visual feedback.

[image]

Comment: +1 And I would use positive wording for both buttons. So ‘No, keep order’ for the No-button. But red for Yes always confuses me.

Comment: I'd suggest "[No, keep order] / [Yes, cancel order]", to add on to what @gerstemout suggested. "Cancel **order**" is a more clear description of what will happen. "Cancel" by itself usually means to not do something. Adding the "order" to the button as well clarifies the action.

Comment: Agree with @maxathousand: "Cancel" on it's own could be taken as "Cancel the _Cancel order_ command".

Comment: Totally agree with the suggestions provided by @maxathousand

Answer (score 2):

I would divide it so that the main link is a button and the secondary is a link underneath.

[ Yes, cancel this order ]

No, keep my order